# AlertDialog whitout border on Android<3.0

Tags: android, dialog, border, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to show an AlertDialog that has a List. When I run the aplication on Android IC I haven't any problem, but when I try it on Android 2.3  the AlertDialog appears with an horrible border that it's on the superior and on the inferior part of the View.
I've tried with themes and with many things, but I've the problem added that AlertDialog.Builder(Context, Theme) is not valid on APIs below 11.
Do you know any solution? Thanks!

```
public boolean updialog (String table) {
    String [] data = bd.List(1, table);
    if(data[0]=="") {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        View view = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.drop_no_resquest, null);
        dialog.setView(view); dialog.create();
        dialog.show(); 
        return true;
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(a);
    View view = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.drop, null);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.drop_listview);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adap = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getApplicationContext(), 
    R.layout.list_item_custom,R.id.list_item_custom_text,data);
    lv.setAdapter(adap);
    dialog.setView(view);
    dialog.create();
    dialog.show(); return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.ThemeDialogCustom);
```

where `ThemeDialogCustom` will look like this

```
 <style name="ThemeDialogCustom">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
</style>
```

**For android < 3.0**
you need to use `Dialog` class.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.ThemeDialogCustom);
    View view = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.drop, null);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.drop_listview);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item_custom,
            R.id.list_item_custom_text, data);
    lv.setAdapter(adap);
    dialog.setView(view);

    dialog.show();
```

Comment: But AlertDialog.Builder(context,theme) was introduced on API 11, How can I add a theme on API<11? Thanks!

Comment: oh my bad! Then I guess there is no option other then this.

Comment: Thanks very much, I took three days thinking about how I can resolve this, but I don't think in use the Dialog class xD Now it work and I can continue!

Answer (score 0):

You can also get rid of the background using dialog.getwindow () and accessing the window properties of the dialog. I think you can use setbackground () and set a transparent drawable to it.